# Crystal reports shows all the rows of table even when rows are filtered C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In crystal reports I always get same result even on different queries

```
var command="Select ID,Nam,Family From Info where ID=2";
var connection=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=data.mdb");
var dt=new DataTable();
 using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, Connect))
            da.Fill(dt);
var report=new Report();//prebuilt report
report.SetDataSource(dt);
CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource=report;
```

"dt" has correct data but I don't know why report shows all of the records

any idea where the problem is?

Comment: may be you need to refresh your command object everytime on the report and in code. Just guessing.

Comment: thank you for answering, I found the answer: instead of dataTable i should use dataSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after a lot of search:

I should use DataSet instead of DataTable

```
var command="Select ID,Nam,Family From Info where ID=2";
var connection=new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data       Source=data.mdb");
var dt=new DataSet();//Here was the problem
 using (var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command, Connect))
            da.Fill(dt);
var report=new Report();//prebuilt report
report.SetDataSource(dt);
CrystalReportViewer.ReportSource=report;
```

Actually if you want to use DataTable you should do this:

```
report.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(dataTable);
```